# Trigger build only on pushes to master

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins with the [Github Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) I have integrated it  using GitHub's webhooks and it works like a charm, except that builds get triggered everytime something is pushed to the repository.

Is there a way to limit builds only when a change to the remote branch `master` has been made?

Comment: __Q:__ What do you mean, with changes have been made to a remote branch? A GitHub git repo, can contain branches, __not__ remote branches.

Comment: **A**: github IS his remote.  He is asking how to limit builds to only when the branch 'master' is updated on github

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Action Plan**

- Open the Jenkins job Configuration
- Go to the section *Source Code Managment*
- In the *Git* section

  - For the field *Branches to build* add the value ***/master**

This tells this Jenkins Job, to only execute the job, when something is pushed to the branch *master*.

**Figure:** Shows the configuration, for building only branch *master*.

[image]

Comment: That did not work for me. The pull request to develop branch triggered Jenkins job with '*/master' branch setting.

Comment: I have `refs/heads/master` in Branch Specifier input now. In addition to that the build is parameterized with Name "sha1" and Default Value "master". And there is Whitelist Target Branches: "master" in Build Triggers advanced options.

Comment: For me it wasn't working because I didn't have the option for pipeline/workflow. Ended up making a trigger to that pipeline with a normal freestyle project.

Comment: the answer is not correct because the job will execute for all changes in all branches, and it just build master in all the execution triggers.

Comment: As @SaeedMohtasham said, this answer is not correct. Shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: this answer is not correct. Shouldn't be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pipeline job with the [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when-example) clause is a possible option.

Here is a sample that checks out **all** branches from your repo and scans the branches using `git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/remotes/` so see which branch was updated last. If `main` was updated most recently then checks it out and runs other stages.

```
def do_build = true

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout SCM') {
          steps {
            // checkout all branches
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
              branches: [[name: '*/*']],
              userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId:  'YOUR_JENKINS_SSH_KEY', url: 'ssh://git@<YOUR-GIT-REPO-URL>']]])
            script {
              def last_git = sh (
                  script: 'git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/remotes/',
                  returnStdout: true
              ).trim()
              do_build = last_git.endsWith("main")
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Build') {
          when {
            expression { do_build }
          }
          steps {
            echo "checkout main"
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
              branches: [[name: '*/main']],
              userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId:  'YOUR_JENKINS_SSH_KEY', url: 'ssh://git@<YOUR-GIT-REPO-URL>']]])
            // DO OTHER STUFF ON MAIN BRANCH E.G. TESTS
          }
        }
    }
}
```