# Jenkins Gitlab integration - build on pushes to master branch only

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have the same question as this one:
[Trigger build only on pushes to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113400/trigger-build-only-on-pushes-to-master)

Only the answer there is not correct. Does anybody know a solution? What sense does it even make to build a certain branch on pushes to any other branch than itself? What I mean to say is that this should really be a very common thing...

In the advanced section of Build Triggers, there's this section, that really looks like the thing:

[image]

However, it doesn't work for me. Like this, it does not trigger the build at all. I also tried putting there just *master* (without the asterisk) but that doesn't help.

If I select the first option (Allow all branches...) then it works, but obviously all the pushes to any branch triggers the build on master which makes no sense.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What plugin do you use ?

Comment: I use Gitlab Plugin. Sorry if that was not obvious: https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/

Comment: I highly recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-branch-source-plugin In my opinion it integrates GitLab with Jenkins in a great way

Answer (score 0):

To integrate GitLab with Jenkins I'd suggest using [Gitlab Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/)

1. Install Gitlab plugin on Jenkins and configure Gitlab Connection (Manage Jenkins -> Configure -> Gitlab), for this you need to create new credentials of type **GitLab API token**.
2. Select trigger in Jenkins job configuration `Build when a change is pushed to GitLab` (when you click on advanced options there is **Secret token** which should be used together with webhook URL in Gitlab Webhooks).
3. [Add webhook](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/integrations/webhooks) (Push Events) in Gitlab `project Settings -> Integrations`, with url and token from Jenkins job and [filter them by branch name](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/integrations/webhooks#branch-filtering).

Update: So my original point was to filter push events on GitLab so Jenkins doesn't need to do it but as you pointed out it should work with Jenkins filter as well.

I tried filtering branch in my job and Jenkins displayed dropdown list with suggested branches after I started typing, then when I choose brach a label appeared `Matching 1 branch`:
[image: Filter Jenkins push trigger]
On the other hand in your screenshot there is some `ERROR` indicator which would suggest that your GitLab connection is improperly configured. I'd suggest to go to test your connection to GitLab and fix it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, however, I cannot open any of the links in step 3 - always gives me timeout. Also, looking at my original post. As I said, it works for me when I select in the Jenkins job settings that all branches should trigger the build. But if I need to filter the branches not in the job settings but within the GitLab project settings, what then is the filter in Jenkins job for? It really looks like it should do what I want. Only it doesn't...

Comment: Fixed, sorry for that.

Comment: I updated the answer after I noticed `ERROR` on your screenshot. You should test your GitLab connection.